# How deep underwater is Rapture?

Tags: bioshock-series

I was curious how deep Rapture (from Bioshock) is, and what the pressure is like at that depth.

Comment: Really not cool putting spoilers that do not relate to the game in question without an explicit indication as such...

Comment: Hi @RilgonArcsinh! Is it better now?

Comment: The question needs significant grammatical cleanup and the bolding is entirely unnecessary, but yes, the unrelated spoiler is at least gone.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Without the spoiler, the question may be seen as idle curiosity by voters.

Comment: @badp I am not insinuating that the spoiler is unrelated to the question, but that it is unrelated to Bioshock 1. There should be a disclaimer **outside the spoiler** stating that it is for Bioshock Infinite for people who've finished Bioshock 1 but not Infinite and mouse over it assuming it's a Bioshock 1 spoiler.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Nobody's stopping you from editing the post and adding spoiler warnings yourself, mind...

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I also retagged the question

Comment: There is no need to have the spoiler there, as it is technically unrelated to the question.  The information can be applied to the situation, certainly, but leave that application to the discretion of the reader.

Comment: This is approximately 2888 PSI... I'm really doubting the feasibility of Rapture even further now.

Comment: @Keavon, one tends not to use feasibility religiously, when playing a video game.

Answer (score 3):

According to data where [Rapture from Wikia](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Rapture) and **Google Earth** it is 2096 meters underwater.

At that depth the pressure would be roughly 200 atmospheres according to [this calculator](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/other/games/depth_press).

Comment: Did you just give the answer to your own question at the same moment that you asked it?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma This is fine.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Usually it is only done for questions that have legitimate merit and obvious broad-base usefulness, but yes, it's a codified "allowed" thing. People's opinions of this range greatly, as you'd expect.

Comment: Or if you stumble over the solution just after posting the question. It's happened to me.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this article](http://www.southernfriedscience.com/?p=18192) Rapture is 150 metres under water.

Comment: The article bases that conclusion entirely off the limits of technology in real life. **BioShock is a video game.** You can not use "that technology only allows 150 meters IRL" as an argument when the main character is running around shooting fire out of his hands.